# Why do I have an issue with synchronization?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Why doesn't variable named 'count' finally equal to 20000?

```
public class Main {
private Integer count = 0;

public void increment() {
    synchronized (count) {
        count++;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main app = new Main();
    app.doWork();
}

public void doWork() {

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
                increment();
            }
        }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
                increment();
            }
        }
    });

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

It seems that thread loses the variable but when does it happen? The same happens in a case of using AtomicInteger too.

P.S. could you please recommend a good course with exercises for learning multithreading in Java?)

Comment: As to your question in the end read jcip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You synchronize on `count`. But your code changes `count`. Different threads synchronizing on different objects don't guarantee atomicity.

Use a separate `final` monitor object to synchronize on.

See also @BackSlash 's answer for making sure you print the correct end result.

***Edit***

His answer comes down to : if you print the result without waiting for the threads to finish on your main thread you'll see some intermediate result, or possibly even 0.

So you need to call `join()`, which blocks until the thread finishes, on both threads before printing the end result.

Comment: there is only one "count" object

Comment: @Mick count is an `Integer` object - and since `Integer` objects are immutable count is a different object for each value of count

Comment: @Mick There is only one count reference, after each increase, it refers to a different object.

Comment: d'oh! Thanks for your explanation. It totally missed out that "count++" is creating a new object.

Comment: @Mick automatic boxing/unboxing can be tricky to spot

Comment: @Gray edited my answer, as requested

Answer (score 3):

Because `start` creates a new thread, and when you print the count you aren't sure the thread execution is finished.

```
t1.start();
t2.start();

System.out.println(count); // Here you don't know if t1 and t2 ended their execution
```

Join threads to wait for them to complete the task:

```
t1.start();
t2.start();

t1.join(); // wait for t1 to finish
t2.join(); // wait for t2 to finish

System.out.println(count); // 20000
```

Note: You'll have to handle `InterruptedException` on `join` calls.

Comment: Thank you for an answer but to my mind, @bowmore is right in this particular situation

Comment: @PavelPavel It isn't. Your question was "Why doesn't variable named 'count' finally equal to 20000?" and the answer is "because you aren't waiting for the threads to terminate". bowmore, to answer this particular question, told you to read my answer.

Comment: Yes. I've made 2 mistakes